# 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'base_dtype' in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have below code which I am trying to understand keras mean  and want to get pooled_grads print. While printing I am getting below error

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

arr3 = np.array([ [
                   [1,2,3],
                   [4,5,6]
                 ],
                 [
                   [1,2,3],
                   [4,5,6]
                 ],
                 [
                   [1,2,3],
                   [4,5,6]
                 ]
                ] 
               )

#print("Arr shape", arr3.shape)

import keras.backend as K

import numpy as np

pooled_grads = K.mean(arr3, axis=(0, 1, 2))

print("------------------------")

print(pooled_grads)
```

I am getting below error

AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'

Comment: Since the `arr3` is 3d, `K.mean(arr3)` is equivalent to `K.mean(arr3, axis=(0,1,2))`

Comment: P.S. I believe the error is not on the `print(pooled_grads)` but on the `K.mean(arr3, axis=(0,1,2))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Keras backend functions expect Keras tensors as inputs. If you want to use a NumPy array as input, convert it to a tensor first, for example with `K.constant`:

```
pooled_grads = K.mean(K.constant(arr3), axis=(0, 1, 2))
```

Note that `pooled_grads` here will be another tensor, so printing it will not give you the value directly, but just a reference to the tensor object. In order to get the value of the tensor, you can use for example `K.get_value`:

```
print(K.get_value(pooled_grads))
# 3.5
```

Comment: I had the same error with `K.clip()` function.

`K.constant` didn't work, so I solved it with `tf.convert_to_tensor()` and passing the tensors to the Keras `clip()` function